Is it haram to work for a scamming company?
A company is doing scams and our job is to filter the customer. For example we are supposed to ask the customer some questions and tell him to do tasks and to get money, he will get money for the tasks and our work is done. Then we forward the customer to someone else and they perform the rest of the scam.
Is working like this Halal or Haram? Because what we tell the customers is right but we know in future they will be scammed.

Assisting in the commission of a sin is itself a sin and is haram.

ولا تعاونوا على الإثم والعدوان
Do not help one another in sin and transgression
— Quran 5:2

